# How to get a bookmark name the Word REF field is pointing to in VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-word

Word REF fields are always pointing to a bookmark by the bookmark's name (excluding the case when they have a blank bookmark name). Given a Word REF field stored in Field object, what is the best way to get the bookmark name that REF field object points to in VBA?

Field object has the following useful members:

1. `Field.Type`: can be compared against `wdFieldRef` to confirm that we are working with the REF field and not some other type of field
2. `Field.Code.Text`: can be used to extract entire field code, e.g. `REF MyBookmark \* Upper`

However, I can't find any members where the content of the field code would be parsed by Word into bookmark name and the rest of the options. Yet clearly Word does that parsing internally in order to render the REF fields correctly. I surely could write my own code to parse the `Field.Code.Text`, but there are several issues with that:

1. It is not a good practice to duplicate functionality because at some point there will be discrepancy in how my code parses the field code and how different past, present and future versions of Word internally parse the field code.
2. There is no authoritative source for the format specification for the REF field codes syntax, so writing your own parser would be an exercise in reverse engineering, which is never reliable.
3. Remarkably, even Word, at least Word 2007, seems to have two different parsers for the REF field hidden somewhere inside, as, for example, the field code `{REF \n MyBookmark}` is processed in the document text without a complaint despite reverse order of the options and the bookmark name, yet when one invokes Edit Field dialog, it points to (none) bookmark due to said reverse order of parameters. Even worse, if you do the same trick with `{REF \* Upper MyBookmark}` code, the Edit Field dialog suddenly recognizes bookmark name just fine despite reverse order.
4. There are also multiple inconsistencies how whitespace is interpreted between and inside the options, again, yielding different results between how Word interprets the field code in text and in Edit Field dialog.

So trying to replicate all of that mess in my own parser is surely a bad idea. Is there any other way to fetch the parsed version of the field code components, at least a bookmark name?

Comment: You are correct that this is non-trivial and that it would be great to be able to re-use some existing parser. But IMO *in the general case* it is at best *not easy to do*, because a field code is not just a sequence of plain text tokens. Field arguments may contain formatting, and field codes may be nested (e.g you might have { REF "x{ IF a = b "c" "d" }" } and therefore need to evaluate the IF to determine the bookmark name).

I don't know of anything open source with much to offer, suspect proprietary APIs such as Aspose have probably got a lot further.

Comment: @jonsson, thank you for your input, nesting even further adds to the complexity indeed.