# Word VBA REF field is not updated in IF field alternative branch

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

Consider a simple Word document which contains three things:

1. A bookmarked portion of the text to be used as a lookup value (bookmark name is *a_bookmark*)
2. A legacy dropdown control to allow user to select one of two options (control bookmark name is *a_control*, option values are `"One"` and `"Two"`, with "One" currently selected)
3. `IF` field that analyzes the value of *a_control* dropdown and generates a fixed text if dropdown has a value of `"One"`, and a lookup value stored in *a_bookmark* bookmark otherwise.

So the IF field code looks like this:

```
{ IF { REF a_control } = "One" "Fixed value" { REF a_bookmark } }
```

Actually, the dropdown is not essential in this scenario, it is only used here to show that the execution of both branches of IF field is theoretically possible. In principle, one can further reduce this example to the following:

```
{ IF 1 = 1 "Fixed value" { REF a_bookmark } }
```

So basically we use a lookup value in the branch that **will not currently** execute. In case of the dropdown this is achieved by the fact that the dropdown currently contains a value of "One" so that the main branch of the IF field is executed. In case of the simplified example this is achieved by virtue of 1 = 1 tautology.

Bottom line is that `{ REF a_bookmark }` **will not be currently** executed, **but it can be** executed in principle in future when conditions change.

Finally one more setup: imagine that the text inside of the *a_bookmark* bookmark has changed for some legitimate reason and we want it to be reflected (updated) in `{ REF a_bookmark }` lookup.

Here is the problem: I can't force the update of the `{ REF a_bookmark }` field either from VBA or from Word no matter what I try. So far I have tried:

1. Iterating through the fields in VBA, finding the field of interest and calling its `Update` method. No result, its `Result.Text` property continues to hold some old value.
2. Updating all fields programmatically: `ThisDocument.Fields.Update`
3. Invoking print preview programmatically: `ThisDocument.PrintPreview` (yes, *Update fields before printing* option is on)
4. Invoking print preview from GUI
5. Expanding the `IF` field entirely in GUI with Shift-F9, then selecting `{ REF a_bookmark }` field in that expansion and invoking *Update field* context menu option specifically for that field.

So it seems to me that Word 2007 is just refusing to update a field that is nested into currently passive branch of the `IF` field, even if I talk to this field directly in VBA. Does anyone know a way to force-update such field?

**Update**: No, *"just wait until the user selects the alternative option and the field will become an active branch and will update on its own"* solution is not suitable, the reason I need the field update NOW is because VB script needs to replace that field with its actual value (unlink the field) at the time of running the script, way before the user will be using the document.

Answer (score 0):

(It's a while since you posted, so I expect you found a way to deal with this. But...)

I was able to replicate this problem. I was surprised.

What to do depends partly on what the bookmark might contain.

If it's just a piece of text, then you could start with

```
{ IF { REF a_control } = "One" "Fixed value" "{ REF a_bookmark }" }
```

then, if you know that field index of that `{ REF a_bookmark }` field is 10 (say),

- unprotect the document for forms

use, e.g.

```
With ActiveDocument.Fields(10)
  .Result.Text = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a_bookmark").Range.Text
  .Unlink
End With
```

- reprotect for forms if that is what you need.

or if it could contain non-text material such as images, then

```
With ActiveDocument.Fields(10)
  .Result.FormattedText = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a_bookmark").Range.FormattedText
  .Unlink
End With
```

But, be aware that if `a_bookmark` contains anything that Word would treat as a double quotation mark, the `IF` field containing the `{ REF a_bookmark }` field will resolve as you might hope, whereas the `IF` field containing the content from the `a_bookmark` bookmark will be truncated after that mark. i.e. if you had to avoid that you'd have to process the bookmark text to deal with that problem.

Also, if you have to use an approach like that, you might be able to avoid having a `{ REF a_bookmark }` field in the `IF` field in the first place, and just use another bookmark to indicate where you should put the content of `a_bookmark`. e.g.

```
{ IF { REF a_control } = "One" "Fixed value" "" }
```

but insert a point bookmark called `b_bookmark` between the final `""`.

Then, e.g.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("b_bookmark").Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("a_bookmark").Range.Text
```

or whatever.

Comment: This method implies that I know the bookmark name referred to in the REF field. In my use case there are literally hundreds of such fields that need to be programmatically unlinked, so I can't hardcode the name of the bookmark, as it is different for every IF/REF pair. And fetching the name of the bookmark from the REF field programmatically has proven to be very ambiguous and unreliable (see this post of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76923717/how-to-get-a-bookmark-name-the-word-ref-field-is-pointing-to-in-vba-code

Comment: So what I ended up doing to solve the problem is this: iterate through all fields, detect a nested REF field through completely magic method (basically Copy method fails with exception on such fields due to unexplained reasons, so I trap that exception), then create a new blank REF field in the end of the document and copy the Code.Text of my field into its Code.Text property, truncating "REF" in the beginning, force-update the new field, then copy its Result.Text into Result.Text of the nested field, finally erase temporary field at the end of the document. Ugly, but it works.

Comment: @RegusPregus since the document cannot actually work properly as it is, I suppose I'd try to modify it so that it could. What I'd probably start  with is *something like* mark the places where I needed to insert the bookmarked text with bookmarks (as I suggested) with a name related to the original name, e.g. use x_a_bookmark to "link" to a_bookmark, then iterate through all bookmarks starting with names starting with "x_" and replace their content with the "linked" bookmark content, I.e. a_bookmark. But maybe you aren't in a position to do that.